# RoR Capistano deploy:migrate uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm running Ubuntu on EC2 and using Capistrano to deploy my app.
Capistrano won't let me run "rake db:schema:load" so I used rails to create a new migration called CreateTables. Then I copied in the create_tables from the schema.rb and ran "cap deploy:migrate".

But, I get this error: uninitialized constant CreateTables

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You need to give more specific details. Why can't you run rake? What is the exact error message, it has to be more than that?

Comment: I'm running rake via the "cap deploy:migrate" command.  Capistrano  runs the migrate rake task. And it is running it.  But, rake is giving me an error "uninitialized constant CreateTables". The migrate file is called "20120508174807_create_tables.rb" and the first few commands are:  ` class CreateTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    create_table "billmethods", :force => true do |t|
      t.string   "method_name"
      t.text     "method_desc"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
    end `

Comment: My understanding is that Capistrano won't let you run rake db:schema:load.  Some developers modify the deploy:cold to do it.

Comment: I can logon to the EC2 server (Ubuntu running RoR) via ssh and get the command prompt.  But, I don't know how to run rake from there.

Comment: I edited the .rb migration file - changed "def change" to "def up".  But, that didn't fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when I tried $ cap deploy:cold, I was able to get the tables created via a migration.